# RStudio - File not found error, but file exists

Tags: r, rstudio

I just completed installing MiKTeX 2.9 on my work laptop so that I can using it with RStudio v1.0.153.
I'm run just the default R Notebook file that you get when you select New >> R Notebook. After I save it and click Knit, the following errors come up:

```
  processing file: test7.Rmd
  |...........................................                      |  67%
label: unnamed-chunk-1
  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: test7.knit.md

"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test7.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output test7.pdf --template "C:\Rpackages\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine xelatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in" 
! LaTeX Error: File `mathspec.sty' not found.

Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)

Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

l.12   \else

pandoc.exe: Error producing PDF
Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 43
In addition: Warning message:
running command '"C:/Program Files/RStudio/bin/pandoc/pandoc" +RTS -K512m -RTS test7.utf8.md --to latex --from markdown+autolink_bare_uris+ascii_identifiers+tex_math_single_backslash --output test7.pdf --template "C:\Rpackages\rmarkdown\rmd\latex\default-1.17.0.2.tex" --highlight-style tango --latex-engine xelatex --variable graphics=yes --variable "geometry:margin=1in"' had status 43 
Execution halted
```

The first error I see is `! LaTeX Error: File`mathspec.sty' not found.` but when I go into MiKTeX Console, I can see that the file is actually there:
[image]

So maybe R is looking in the wrong place for this package. The computer has a few firewalls which I think might be causing these issues. '
Can someone please assist me in identifying where the problem might be?

Thank you

Comment: No. You see it was packaged, not that it was installed.

Comment: yes I see that now. Why didn't any of these get installed during the installation? This seems to have worked for me on my personal computer easily.

Comment: Maybe you had basic install, not a full install.

Comment: Yes you are right, it was the Basic. I'm going to get IT to install the Net Installer. Looks like that should fix it. 
Thank you

Comment: If you want to typeset in hieroglyphic ot linearA or classic Mongolian… Don't forget MiKTeX proposes to install missing packages on  the fly.

Comment: When we installed MiKTex, we've selected Yes to installing packages on the fly. So I'm assuming that the reason it is not working is because of firewalls. 
For example, when I go into the Console and right-click on the package and select Install, I get SLL Connect Error (no further info).
If there is another way to install those packages withouth Admin support, please let me know or point me in the direction. 
I've looked up installing packages manually, maybe thats the way.

Comment: If you install texlive all the packages are there. Otherwise you can download them from CTAN and put them either in the TeX path or in the folder of the file you are compiling

Comment: Maybe you can change repository. It's hard to say what happens if you have no details. Personally, I downloaded the contents of a repository on my computer with Filezilla, and update it regularly, then install and update what I need  from a local repository.